# Facebook graph api doesn't return url shares count anymore

Tags: facebook

I can't retrieve url shares count anymore from https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.somewhere.com/over/the/rainbow/ 
Does anybody know why?

Comment: I had the same problem!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061877/facebook-graph-api-url-comments-and-shares-count-doesnt-work-anymore/

Hope this could help.